# How to make the client server socket program asynchronous?

Tags: c, sockets

I have the below code for the client and server.

It uses socket programming for the communication in linux.

Client

```
...
//after connecting to the server
while(1){
recv();//recv from the serv
//get user input using scanf()
send();
}
...
```

Server

```
...
//Create a thread to handle each client request
//Inside client thread
while(1){
send()
...
recv()
}
...
```

Here client gets the message from only after sending something to the server.
But I need to receive the message even without sending anything to the server.
Do I need to handle this through multi threading in client? Or any other way?

Comment: And how does server knows about the client? Does this not defeat the whole concept of "client-server" architecture?

Comment: Why not to look for a freely available simple client/server example codes, such as "chat" one?

Comment: @EugeneSh.  Whatever I am getting in search has a pair of send and recv. I need something like server keeps on texting multiple times and client can reply back whenever it feels like. But here what happens is server sends something and client has to reply to that to get the next message from the server.

Comment: Is this a school project? why not use an existing library, like libuv or facil.io for the network layer?